# Angular2 OverlayComponent not updating message variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the below OverlayComponent that's serving as a processing spinner during async calls. The overlay pops up without issue but when I try and pass a message to it, the message doesn't stick.

**Child Component**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {OverlayComponent} from "../../shared/app.mysite.overlay.component";


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'tracker-component',
    templateUrl: '/public/app/templates/pages/racker/mysite.tracker.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../../scss/pages/tracker/tracker.css'],
    providers: [OverlayComponent]
})

export class TrackerComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(private overlayComponent: OverlayComponent) {

    }
    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.overlayComponent.showOverlay("Testing 123"); //<-- shows overlay but doesn't show the message in the overlay            
    }    
}
```

**Child Component HTML**

```
<div id="TrackerContainer">    
    <div class="col-lg-12" class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-header">
            <div>
                <div id="pageTitle">Tracker</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-container container">
            <div *ngFor="let item of tracker.activeMenu.items">
                <card-component [item]="item"></card-component>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<overlay-component [message]="overlayMessage"></overlay-component>
```

**OverlayComponent.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    

@Component({    
    selector: 'overlay-component',
    templateUrl: '/public/app/templates/shared/mysite.overlay.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../app/scss/shared/overlay.css']    
})

export class OverlayComponent  {

    message: string;
    //message: string = 'testing...'; <-- this updated the message just fine
    showOverlay(msg: string) {
        this.message = msg; // <-- the right value comes through in the msg variable but doesn't update in the page
        $('.overlay-component-container').show();
    }

    hideOverlay() {
        $('.overlay-component-container').hide();
        this.message = '';
    }    
}
```

**OverlayComponent.html**

```
<div class="overlay-component-container">
    <div class="overlay-component">
        <div class="overlay-message">{{message}}</div>
        <div>
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add code of `mysite.tracker.component.html`?

Comment: I think you provide OverlayComponent in providers array but want to show another component. This `$('.overlay-component-container')` also is very bad.

Comment: Yes, I will be handling the hide/show differently with angular2 class logic but I'm trying to create a super example first

Comment: @yurzui I added the html.

Comment: Are you seeking to have the overlay/spinner cover the entire page? I think the answer is yes, but wanted to confirm b4 i answer

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4):

The issue could be caused by a few things:

You don't need this here, this is just for services, not for components

```
providers: [OverlayComponent]
```

This isn't the way to get a reference to another component, you may not have the correct instance.

```
constructor(private overlayComponent: OverlayComponent)
```

Is `<overlay-component>` actually inside the HTML of the Tracker component?

Also where is the overlayMessage property on the tracker component? (as used below)

```
<overlay-component [message]="overlayMessage"></overlay-component>
```

Just ensure that the over-component is inside the tracker component, remove the `this.message = msg; from showOverlay()` and use two-way data binding to change the message.

I.E `<overlay-component [message]="overlayMessage"></overlay-component>`

If you add overlayMessage: string; to your Tracker component (or parent component of the overlay) Then all you need to do is update it in your parent component and your overlay component will pick up the changes.